# How to create a rotating image slider in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I'm building a simple image viewing app. I need to display images in a control which user can swipe and move to the next one until the end and then moves to the first slide. WinRT FlipView does not behave like this it stops from the last image. Is it possible to create something like that manually? I'm not familiar with gestures and tried to detect the swipe and do it.But I couldn't manage to get the image sliding effect with the finger like it happens in FlipView. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend **Syncfusion controls for WinRT Xaml**.

They have an excellent Carousel control that may meet your requirement.

User can swipe to move to next & previous slide.

Please go through the following link for more details,

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/carousel

Comment: Yes but it costs $399 and it doesn't repeat!